# What's the easiest way to sync the state of backbone models across users? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, backbone.js, coffeescript

What's the easiest way to sync the state of backbone models across users? I'm running a node.js server. All communication is done vis websockets. I want to set it up so that models can be pushed to different clients and any shared models automatically maintain state across all these clients if any changes are made.

What is the easiest / most reliable way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that **Backbone.IO** can help you: https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io

It's easy to share models across users with that.